# Can I use the find command to pass arguments to perl?

Tags: find, perl

I have a perl script

```
$ cat ~/script.pl
sub main {

    my ($file) = @_;

    <STUFF>

    }

}

foreach (@ARGV) {

    main($_);

}
```

I want to execute `~/script.pl` on every `.txt` file under the directory `~/foo`. I can get the list of `.txt` files under `~/foo` with the command

```
$ find ~/foo -type f -name \*.txt
```

Can I somehow use this command to pass these files to my script?

Comment: You have a logic error in `my $file = @_;` -- since the left-hand side is a scalar context, $file will contain the scalar representation of @_, which will be the *number* of elements in that list. To assign the arguments to scalar variables, you need parentheses: `my ($file) = @_;` or use `my $file = shift;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to accomplish this with the `find` command.  I'll list some in the order that I think is important for understanding in your situation.

1. Your script appears to accept multiple filename arguments, so the most efficient and nearly universal way to accomplish this using the `find` command is:

   ```
   find ~/foo -type f -name \*.txt -exec perl ~/script.pl {} +
   ```

   This executes your script with as many found filename arguments as possible.  Your script will be called multiple times if necessary to process all filenames. Note the `+` at the end of the line.
2. This is the original and most universal method. This is less efficient for your situation because it invokes `perl` once for each file found. This usage has been available since [the earliest days of Unix](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/find). Note the escaped semi-colon (`\;`) at the end of the line (as opposed to the `+` above).

   ```
   find ~/foo -type f -name \*.txt -exec perl ~/script.pl {} \;
   ```
3. Before the `-exec ... +` syntax was added to `find`, the `xargs` command was invented to help increase efficiency when processing lists of filenames or other arguments.  This works almost identically to the `-exec ... +` example above:

   ```
   find ~/foo -type f -name \*.txt -print | xargs perl ~/script.pl
   ```

   If your implementation supports it, you should use the `-print0` option of `find`, along with the `-0` argument to `xargs`.  This causes `find` to print null characters between argument strings and prevents `xargs` from splitting arguments on anything but the null character. This helps to prevent `xargs` from splitting arguments incorrectly, in the event that your filenames contain whitespace or some other special characters.

   Using the `-exec ... +` syntax is generally a better idea because `find` then puts the filenames directly into your script's argument list, eliminating a process, and avoiding any interpretation that might happen by piping to `xargs`. However, `xargs` might have advantages if you need more control over the process.  See the `xargs` man page.
4. You can also check out the `find2perl` command which takes the same arguments as `find` and prints a `perl` program to do the same thing.  You could then incorporate the generated `perl` code into your script.  In the generated script below you would modify the next to the last line to call your function instead of `print`.

   ```
   $ find2perl foo -type f -name \*.txt    # /*

   #[some preamble code removed for brevity]

   # Traverse desired filesystems
   File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, 'foo');
   exit;

   sub wanted {
       my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

       (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
       -f _ &&
       /^.*\.txt\z/s
       && print("$name\n");
   }
   ```

Comment: In the second command how many times is the script called? Would it not be just once?

Comment: Maybe.  It depends how many files you find.  `xargs` will batch them up so it will call your script with close to the maximum command line length each time (without going over).  If you want to find out for your case, add the `-t` (trace) option to `xargs`.

Comment: You might also want to mention find's `-exec ... +` instead of `;`. Like `xargs`, that will also try to combine everything into as few commands as possible.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers indicate - yes you can.

I will suggest an alternative - don't, and use the perl built in `File::Find` instead - which lets you do basically the same thing, but self contained.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

sub process {
    return unless -f;
    return unless m/\.txt$/; #regex style, not shell glob. 
    print "Found: Name of $_ as path $File::Find::name in $File::Find::dir\n"; 
}

find ( \&process, '~/foo' );
```

You can either hardcode the path (`~/foo`) or read it from `@ARGV`.

```
 find ( \&process, @ARGV ); #takes as many paths as you specify as args.
```

Comment: This looks cool. I assume this is more efficient than my original idea?

Comment: I won't say more efficient, because they're doing the same thing - the expensive part is the filesystem traversal. However it does mean that you're being self contained, which means you don't get tripped up by (as many) interpolation errors - things like filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `-exec scriptName.sh {} \;` structure

In your particular case that would be

```
find ~/foo -type f -name \*.txt -exec scriptName.sh {} \;
```

Alternative to that would be to pass the files to `xargs`, using null separator.

Taken straight from the xargs manual is this example

```
 find /tmp -name core -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```